# How can I access properties of an object within a list?

Tags: c#, monogame

edit: To clarify the question, I'm trying to tighten up my code by storing multiple objects(which all need to be drawn in different positions and manners and each has custom properties such as shape) in a list. I'd like to be able to access one of these properties from any given object in the list for various purposes, such as drawing a sprite unique to that item in the list, later on in my program.

I'm trying to access properties specific to each individual object in a list I've created but can't seem to get it right. I think I'm missing something fundamental with lists! Here's my class where I define the Islands:

```
class Island
{

    public string IslandName { get; set; }

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

    public Rectangle IslandRectangle { get; set; }

    public Island(string name, Vector2 position, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        name = this.IslandName;
        position = this.Position;
        rectangle = this.IslandRectangle;
    }
}
```

Then, in my Main method, I create a new list of islands(just one for now):

```
List<Island> allIslands = new List<Island>()
    {
        new Island("ShepherdsLookout", new Vector2(200, 200), new Rectangle(200,200, 50, 50))
    };
```

In the draw method of my game, I want to be able to access the rectangle specific to this island, for example instead of writing:

```
spritebatch.draw(sprite, new vector2D(200, 200), new rectangle(200, 200, 50, 50));
```

I'd like to just do something like this pseudocode:

```
spritebatch.draw(sprite, islands.shepherdslookout.position, islands.shepherdslookout.rectangle);
```

I've tried using IEnumerable to do it:

```
 IEnumerable<Island> ShepherdsLookout = from island in allIslands where island.IslandName == "ShepherdsLookout" select island;
```

but that doesn't seem to be working either :/
Do I need a foreach loop or something? I feel like theres some way to do it with Linq but I'm not sure.

Comment: What's the problem? What happened? It sounds like you're trying to find one item from a list; use `.First()`.

Comment: Consider using a `Dictionary<String, Island>`.

Comment: Typically, yes, youll need an iterator. islands.shepherdslookout.position is not a valid accessor call. You have to do something like islands.get(0).position

@SLaks suggestion of using a dictionary is really useful if you ever want to access one by name. You can always access it in the same manner as a list by iterating over the values, but the Dictionary gives you the option of direct access.

Comment: In your constructor for Island you are doing your assignments backwards.  For example you want to do `this.IslandName = name`.

Comment: @levininja good catch, thank you

Comment: @SLaks - Dictionary seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you guys

Comment: I'm not 100% what you're asking, but if you are trying to do some operation on every island, then you want either a foreach loop or you could just put a method on island that does the operation based on its own properties (you can reference these properties like `this.IslandName` from any method that you write on the class).  Hope that helps...if not, I would work on clarifying in your question what exactly you are trying to do and we're more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a couple different things:

1. Using list

   ```
   Island theIsland = islands.Find(x => x.IslandName == "ShepherdsLookout");
   ```
2. Using a dictionary will provide better performance.

   ```
   Dictionary<string, Island> islands = new Dictionary<string, Island>();
   ```

   //Load dictionary data
   Island theIsland = islands["ShephardsLookout"];

Either way you would then use just:

```
theIsland.Position
```

To retrieve the value

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you, @SLaks and the other commenters

Comment: Awesome!  Good Luck